# SQLite: duplicate column error from Create Table

Tags: sqlite

I'm a first time user for SQLite. I'm using command line SQLite, version 3.20.1 2017-08-24 16:21:36 on a Mac

I start SQLite by specifying the db file via the command line:

`sqlite3 ~/www/sqlite/statistics.db`

I try to create a table but receive the error `duplicate column name`

Advice appreciated. In the transcript below, I first tested with a 1 column table.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE api_methods(
   ...>    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
   ...> );
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
api_methods
sqlite> drop table api_methods;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE api_methods(
   ...>    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...>    action_name TEXT NOT NULL
   ...> );
Error: duplicate column name:   
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved when I deleted the leading spaces before the column names:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE api_methods(
   ...> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ...> action_name TEXT NOT NULL
   ...> );
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
api_methods
sqlite> pragma table_info(api_methods);
0|id|INTEGER|0||1
1|action_name|TEXT|1||0
sqlite>
```